# Check for certain text and add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, contains

I need to check with jQuery if there is certain text in an LI and add a class accordingly.

Something along these lines...

```
if ($('ul li:last-child:contains("this text")').length > 0) {
    $(this).addClass("this");
} else if ($('ul li:last-child:contains("that text")').length > 0)
    $(this).addClass("that");
}
```

Obviously, the code above does not work, but hopefully it's close to what I'm needing.  Anyone know how I can write that?

EDIT:
Here is the exact code that worked for me thanks to adeneo's answer below...

```
$('.job-result .job-details ul li:last-child').addClass(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf('Augusta') != -1 ? 'augusta' : 
           $(this).text().indexOf('Aiken') != -1 ? 'aiken' :
           $(this).text().indexOf('Job') != -1 ? 'jobshop' : '';
});
```

Comment: what is `$(this)` referring to ?

Comment: $('ul li:last-child').html() == 'your text'

Comment: Gee.  I appreciate the downvote on the question.  Seemed legitimate to me, and got the answer I was looking for from adeneo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're doing is checking if an element exists by using length, and if it does'nt exist, add a class to that element? That won't work as the element does'nt exist, and inside a conditional like if / else there is no special scope, so `this` has no meaning?

How about just using an anonymous function inside `addClass()` to get the scope and check the content :

```
$('ul li:last-child').addClass(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf('this text') != -1 ? 'this' : 
           $(this).text().indexOf('that text') != -1 ? 'that' : '';
});
```

Comment: This works exactly how I needed it to.  Thanks for the rework on the logic.  I'm adding the exact usage for me in my question to maybe help others.